# How to get psexec to run through python

Tags: python, subprocess, psexec

```
subprocess.Popen( ['C:\\Windows\\System32\\Psexec.exe', '-i','-d','\\\\' + 'ats-107-203575' ,'cmd.exe //c msg * "test"'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

I cant get this to work to save my life I am still new I have looked up alot and found some ideas but none work I am working please help anything would be great thank you!

Comment: What is the problem with that? Any exception?

Comment: Okay so I'm trying to make a client that sends a msg to my friends in my class but I need this line to work and it always fails no matter what I have tried os.system but apparently subprocess.call is better but then I seen something about subprocess.popen and I tried that but still no luck I don't understand what I'm doing wrong I wouldn't have cake to stack overflow unless I really needed help

Comment: But HOW does it fail? Any error messages, exception, wrong behavior?

Comment: Okay sorry I didn't understand what you were asking. In this situation I get could not find file but i put it in system32 and I put that exact code in cmd and it runs so I don't know what the problems is

Comment: as you are using a list of arguments, `shell=True` is a problem. In [the API documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) you see that with `shell=True` you need to provide a single string that is interpreted by windows cmd.

Comment: Also, have a look at `check_call`, which will raise proper exceptions in case things don't work well.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call( ['C:\\Windows\\System32\\Psexec.exe -i -d \\\\fhs-lib-15 -u administrator -p Kys123$! cmd.exe //c msg * "test"'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

Comment: Gave me this error

`subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Windows\\System32\\Psexec.exe -i -d \\\\fhs-lib-15 -u administrator -p Kys123$! cmd.exe //c msg * "test"']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: If you do not use `shell=True`, you need to pass each argument as a separate entry in your list... `subprocess.check_call( ['C:\\Windows\\System32\\Psexec.exe', '-i', '-d'...`

Comment: Okay so I fixed it this is what I did

`from subprocess import *

child=Popen(['C:/PsExec.exe', '-accepteula', '-i', '-d', '-s', '\\\\ats-107-202462', 'cmd.exe', '/c', 'msg', '*', '"Test"'])`

Comment: The problem was my python script could not get into system 32 so I put psexec.exe on the top local :C and then it could connect then after that I realised I didnt need a double forward slash infront of the c switch annnnnddd then I used Popen instead of call because it will remain open insted of closing right away...  also the `shell=True` with commas does work if its in a list.